# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected token '<' cropperjs

Tags: angular, cropperjs

I'm trying to implement cropperjs in my Angular app. Cannot user angular wrapper for cropperjs because of my Angular 4 version.

I have installed cropperjs and imported in my component like this:

```
import Cropper from 'cropperjs/dist/cropper'
```

And I have configured my build config file:

```
  module.exports = {
    bundleConfig: {
    builderConfig: {
      paths: {
        '*': '*.js'
      },
      meta: {
        '@angular/*': { build: false },
        'cropperjs/*': { build: false }
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm getting unexpected token '<' when I'm trying to initialize new cropper:

```
const image = this.imageElement.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement;
      image.src = 'data:image/jpeg:base64, ' + this.base64;
      image.onload = () => {    
        this.cropper1 = new Cropper(image, {
        })
      }
```